# JSF Double Click perform action

Tags: javascript, jsf, double-click

How can I execute a backing bean action when a user double clicks on a menu?
e.g. using a selectManyListbox I assume I would need some javascript to execute a backing bean action using ondblclick.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Dwayne

Comment: Double-clicking isn't really a typical mode of interacting with web pages/applications. The browsers really only understand "click", and most people do too. However, it's usually just a simple matter of a timeout handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:selectManyListBox 
   ondblclick="document.getElementById('yourFormId').submit()" />
```

(or use one of numerous ways to obtain the parent form and submit it)

Comment: Note that this is not part of DOM0 spec, but a defacto standard. Browser support is pretty good, but standards support not.